# Laravel storage

Tags: php, laravel

Возникла проблема при отображении загруженных изображений.
Гружу изображения на диск `public`

```
$img = $request->file('img')->store('news', 'public');
```

Предварительно создав symbol link:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

При загрузке изображения всё ок, изображения сохраняются в `storage` и сразу линкуются в `public`, но когда я пытаюсь вывести в html, Laravel выдаёт 404...

Как я только не пытался выводить изображения и никак!

```
asset('/storage/'.$img); // у img путь news/уник_имя.png
asset($img);
'/public/storage/news/...'
'/storage/news/...'
 и тд и тп
```

Ничего не выходит.

Даже если получить ссылку в контроллере только что загруженного файла и проверить в браузере то 404 так же:

```
$img = $request->file('img')->store('news', 'public');
return Storage::url($img);
```

На всякий случай пути до картинки storage (полные, может тут проблема)

```
project/storage/app/public/news/3QssUS78K7dKjtaWibPPlLmKWTKgQgBbtgkdSegA.png
project/public/storage/news/3QssUS78K7dKjtaWibPPlLmKWTKgQgBbtgkdSegA.png
```

Вытаскиваю изображения из линкованной папки storage, например в папку img (public/img/уник_имя.png) и изображение отображается! В чём проблема?

Comment: на диске файл есть?

Comment: То есть в коде получается `<img src="/storage/news/3QssUS78K7dKjtaWibPPlLmKWTKgQgBbtgkdSegA.png">` и эта ссылка 404?

Comment: @TotalPusher, src="asset('/storage/'.$img)" и получается https://домен/storage/news/3QssUS78K7dKjtaWibPPlLmKWTKgQgBbtgkdSegA.png (404)

Comment: Значит проблема в веб-сервере, а не в PHP и Laravel, правильно? Тогда приложите конфиги всех веб-серверов сюда. И на всяких случай, задите в корень веб-документов и `ls -la /storage/news/3QssUS78K7dKjtaWibPPlLmKWTKgQgBbtgkdSegA.png` что выводит?

Comment: @TotalPusher, Вытаскиваю изображения из линкованной папки storage, например в папку img (public/img/уник_имя.png) и изображение отображается. Сейчас посмотрю

Comment: @TotalPusher, ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/storage/news/AUY8UNL2rmkKIuR2q1fR74hFK0ho8xFazDvrfQyQ.png': Нет такого файла или каталога (Имя другого изображения так же загруженного на сервер) Проверял из /project/

Comment: Сорян, уберите начальный слеш: `ls -la storage/news/3QssUS78K7dKjtaWibPPlLmKWTKgQgBbtgkdSegA.png`. Иначе с корня диска

Comment: @TotalPusher, Спасибо большое за то что указали куда копать! Проблему решил на стороне виртуальной машины Vagrant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил на стороне виртуальной машины Vagrant. Проблема была в том, что там там не линковалась папка `storage`. Хотя синхронизация всех папок и действий должна быть благодаря `Homestead`.